# Laptop screen with horizontal lines gradually appearing

Tags: laptop

I have a Asus ROG GL702VM laptop that's started to show horizontal lines over the top half of the screen.

Initially I thought it was a software problem because a shutdown resolved it, but then it got worse and now I think it must be a weird hardware problem but I'm not sure which part it could be.

The lines start appearing at the top part of the screen, then they start to get worse over time and in about 5 or 10 minutes the whole top half of the screen is covered (including some ghost images).
If the screen turns off for a while the lines go away (if it was off for only a short while it will just improve a bit). If it was off for a long time, the problem takes a few minutes to start again.
I thought it could be a problem with the video RAM, but an external monitor works fine, so I guess it must be an issue with the laptop screen itself especially since it is also present in the BIOS screen and also does not change when changing the screen resoltion.

Anybody know what could be causing this?

Comment: loose connection or (more likely) damaged panel/controller. Either replace the screen or just use an external monitor, if that's an option. If it's showing up while booting at the BIOS screen as you say, then it's clearly not a software issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It must have been a software related issue - it got a lot worse, at one stage the whole screen would go black and I had to restart multiple times to get it back. Then suddenly it just went away completely after a windows update and now I haven't had any more problems for the past 8 months.

Comment: The problem is back after more than a year. Interestingly windows updated at the same time as it started again - very strange. It is still the top part of the screen. Gets worse (darker and darker) over a few minutes period until the top part is unusable - just showing artifacts and lines. Then after closing and opening or restarting it gets better. Now it came back with a washed out appearance, but usable (for now). If anybody else has a similar experience let me know.

Answer (score 0):

It could be 2 things

1. The cable that connects to your screen is damaged and needs to be replaced, or
2. The screen is damaged and needs to be replaced (most likely according to your description)

I don't know if you recently bought this laptop but maybe you can claim your waranty. Usualy they change the faulty part and it should only take no more than 15 days.

And like @wysiwyg said, if you're in a hurry, try and use an external monitor

Comment: I doubt it could be a faulty cable since the problem gradually gets worse. I bought the laptop a little over a year ago when I traveled in the USA, will have to check if the warranty is still active and whether it's international...

Comment: hope it's the cable, because it could be easily replaced and in fact it should be faster than changing the whole screen

Also you could try and test this: 
https://www.quora.com/How-can-you-tell-if-a-laptop-LCD-cable-is-broken-or-the-screen-itself

Comment: Seems like could actually be a software problem after all... a very strange one! First noticed that it is temperature related - if I force both my CPU and GPU fan to be permanently on, it would take longer to start. Also, monitor going off does nothing, but Sleep improves it (long sleep fixes). Then I had a problem with my Ubuntu Virtualbox - the desktop stopped showing in the main area, but showed in the small Preview (after ubuntu update). Eventually managed to fix that by disabling 3D Acceleration in VBox. Since then the problem seems to be gone!?! Hope I'm not jumping the gun and jinxing..

Comment: If its temperature related then you should check for the integrity of your GPU _(its the only thing i can think of)_ because high temperatures can slowly melt the solder on the GPU.
A reflow could be a viable fix but a temporary one, but a 
reballing its a sure fix because it changes the whole solder of the gpu
Hope it helps! 
Have a good week